# STM32F4 Systick timer HAL_SYSTICK_Config() clock value

Tags: stm32, cortex-m4

In STM32F4 controllers, systick timer is configured to generate interrupt on every 1 ms. If clock frequency is changed, then the number of ticks requred for 1ms should be given as a parameter to the function ***HAL_SYSTICK_Config***

This is what is done in the tutorial I'm following
SYSCLOCK = 8 MHz

HCLK = 4 MHZ

APB1 & 2 clock = 2 Mhz

Systick timer prescalar = 1

```
HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);
HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);
```

According this if I want the Systick timer prescalar to 8 then code would change like this

```
HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);
HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK_DIV8);
```

But I don't think this would work. Here HCLK  is 4 MHz but the Systick timer clock is infact 500 KHz (4Mhz / 8).  For the first code, since the prescalar is 1, it wouldn't be an issue.

Shouldn't the prescalar configured before configuring the Systick and consider the prescalar value? Like this

```
HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK_DIV8);
HAL_SYSTICK_Config((HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/8)/1000);
```

I thought it could be a mistake from the side of instructor. So searched for STM32 HAl code, these are codes in ***HAL_RCC_ClockConfig*** function which configures systick timer

```
/* Update the SystemCoreClock global variable */
SystemCoreClock = HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq() >> AHBPrescTable[(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_HPRE)>> RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Pos];

/* Configure the source of time base considering new system clocks settings */
HAL_InitTick (uwTickPrio);
```

***HAL_InitTick*** Function

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_InitTick(uint32_t TickPriority)
{
  /* Configure the SysTick to have interrupt in 1ms time basis*/
  if (HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock / (1000U / uwTickFreq)) > 0U)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Configure the SysTick IRQ priority */
  if (TickPriority < (1UL << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS))
  {
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, TickPriority, 0U);
    uwTickPrio = TickPriority;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

uwTickFreq is 1.

you can see that this function is not considering the Systick timer prescalar? It calculates HCLK frequency and then passes that value to HAL_SYSTICK_Config function.  Isn't it important to consider the prescalar for this? Use it calculate what the Systick timer clock freqency.